# Syslog-ng only Logging incoming when running in the forground

Tags: syslog-ng

I've been testing Syslog-ng in a dev environment for several weeks now.  It has since been moved to production but I'm getting weird behavior.  I've taken the exact same syslog-ng.conf that was on dev (listens on udp:514 and writes everything to a file on a separate disk) and have it running on production.  I only seem to get data written to my destination when I run `syslog-ng -Fevd` in the foreground.  Does anyone have any ideas.  I'm tried restarting the service with no luck at all.

This particular syslog-ng is gathering logs from all ESXi and vCenter servers in the production environment, then they get forwarded to Splunk from there (Splunk's recommend solution for VMware logs).

Comment: Add to your question your script, an input example, your script output and the expected output to write a good question and maximize the probability of getting your issue solved

Answer (score 0):

So I continued to pour through the man page.  I compared the command the service runs and cross referenced the options on the man page.  It was using the `-F` for foreground in the service.  So I just ran `sudo syslog-ng --process-mode safe-background` (which is supposed to be the default behavior of syslog-ng) and I'm now getting all of my logs in my destination.

TLDR; RTFM.